# Learning with zero inductive bias

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning

I want to understand the intuition behind the classic setting of learning theory, we always assume that the model belongs to some known class. Was there a formal proof that we can or can not learn a model with zero inductive bias meaning with no knowledge of the hypothesis class?

Comment: One way to put it is that the required sample complexity is known to grow with the VC-dimension of the hypothesis class. If your potential hypothesis class contains all possible functions, it has maximum possible VC-dimension, implying an exponential or infinite sample complexity in a nontrivial setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more precise, if you want a distribution-free generalization bound, then you must have some inductive bias (these are the no-free-lunch theorems referenced by D.W.). For binary classification, this amounts to the hypothesis class having a finite VC-dimension (necessary and sufficient).

If you allow distribution-dependent rates, then finite VC-dimension is no longer necessary. Much less is formally known in this setting, but here is a first step:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.04054
(Cohen, K., "Local Glivenko-Cantelli", COLT 2023).

Finally, if you are content with (say, strong) Bayes-consistency and no rate, then, at least in metric spaces, there is a universal learner without any inductive bias:

https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-49/issue-4/Universal-Bayes-consistency-in-metric-spaces/10.1214/20-AOS2029.full
(Hanneke et al., "Universal Bayes consistency in metric spaces", AOS 2021.)

Comment: Really nice! I'll go through these papers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  See the No free lunch theorem (e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem) and [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/15650/1794) and many other resources).